# xml xpath to match elements of either types in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to match two elements of either type, how to do it in java with xpath?

For example, I have either
`"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><A><e1>a</e1></A>"`
or `"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><B><e2>a</e2></B>"`

And I need to match either `e1` or `e2`.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//e1");
Object result = expr.evaluate(is, XPathConstants.NODESET);//check ((NodeList) result).getLength()
```

And if it does not match, I need to check similarly for `e2`. Is there any simpler and more efficient way, like using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'OR' operator in XPath.
For example

- `(//e1 | //e2)`

Comment: Thanks. But how to tell which one it actually matched?

Comment: XPath (1.0) returns either a node-set or a scalar (number, string or boolean). In this case, the node-set is a *union* of the nodes selected. If you want to distinguish the `//e1` from the `//e2` selections, then you should use separate expressions.